# C# put quotes inside a string before another string

Tags: c#, string, quotes

*Quick question that i cant find an answer online or just dont know how to look for it.
i have a problem with this code*

```
string stackoverflowcommunityisawesome =  "string " + RandomString(5) + " = '" + RandomString(5) + "'; " ;
```

currently the output is :

> string AGKHAOH = 'kaosgkoko';

when i want it to be:

> string AGKHAOH = "kaosgkoko";

I tried putting `@"""` instead of `'"` but the output is like :

> string AGKHAOH = + RandomString(5) +;

Tried with `"\""` as well - the whole code turns red. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: the code snippet is not complete right?
you must be doing something wrong, \" is the escape for double quotes

Comment: Try changing ' to \"

Comment: " = \"" + RandomString(5) + "\"; "

Comment: Look up C# string literals, and verbatim string literals.

Comment: added the whole snippet

Comment: That is a LOT of concatenation.  String.Format or string interpolation would be better.  StringBuilder may also be an option.

Comment: @ZeroSense dude, that's a scary piece of code :p I would try to refactor that.. maybe there are common parts, and as DSway said, with heavy usage... StringBuilder would be definitely the way to go.

Comment: @rmjoia yeah i know its lame code , i just that for a simple task i needed.Thanks for the recommendation on StringBuilder.Im still new to C#

Comment: @ZeroSense dude, don't take me wrong, I was just saying that you can make it better, it was from the heart :)

Comment: @ZeroSense - Your lack of effort in formatting makes this very bad content. Please change that.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko happy?

Comment: Why would your question in any way make me happy? Anyway - no - it's very hard to read.

Comment: @MaciejJureczko now ?

Comment: Much better actually :)

Comment: Although the edit by @CDspace is IMO really bad and makes it really hard to understand...

Comment: @MaciejJureczko now its by your edit , Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just escape the quotes like so: `"\""`.

```
string funone = "public static void "+RandomString(5)+ "(string " + RandomString(5) + ") { " + Environment.NewLine +                    
                "string " + RandomString(5) + " = \"" + RandomString(5) + "\';" 
                + Environment.NewLine + 
                "}";
```

Answer (score 2):

\" is the way to go, if you're getting an error with that then there are errors elsewhere.

Comment: apologies for not refreshing quick enough to see them

Comment: Well comments are meant to ask for clarification, not to provide an answer.

Comment: true.. but when everyone just said the same... ok, take the bike home :) the important is that the OP got his answer..

Comment: orhtej answer is the correct one , thanks a lot guys!.Ill mark it as answered when it lets me

Comment: @ZeroSense don't forget to thank for the time, and mark the one you consider the most correct answer as "answer" and upvote all others, this will help the next person with the same question to find their answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Either use verbatim string literals or escape the " using backslash. This should work.

`string funone = "public static void "+RandomString(5)+ "(string " + RandomString(5) + ") { " + Environment.NewLine + "" + "string " + RandomString(5) + " = \"" + RandomString(5) + "\"; " 
                + Environment.NewLine + "";`

Comment: Thanks for the reply buddy already got an answer but thanks for joining :)

Answer (score 0):

If that is really your code, I would overhaul it:

```
        StringBuilder funone = new StringBuilder();
        funone.AppendLine($"public static void {RandomString(5)} (string {RandomString(5)}) {{");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"byte[] {RandomString(5)} = new byte[{rnd.Next(888, 133333)}];");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"byte[] {RandomString(5)} = new byte[{rnd.Next(888, 133333)}];");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"byte[] {RandomString(5)} = new byte[{rnd.Next(888, 133333)}];");
        funone.AppendLine($"while (true) {{ ");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"byte[] {RandomString(5)} = new byte[{rnd.Next(888, 133333)}];");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"byte[] {RandomString(5)} = new byte[{rnd.Next(888, 133333)}];");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine($"string {RandomString(5)} = \"{RandomString(5)}\";");
        funone.AppendLine("}");
        funone.AppendLine();
        string output = funone.ToString();
        string path = @"C:\core\junk.txt";
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            File.AppendAllText(path, output);
        }
```